# Get repeating events with icalendar

Tags: python, icalendar

I use the [icalendar](https://github.com/collective/icalendar) package to work with my downloaded google calendar `.ics` file

I want to support recurring meetings, they have this line in the `.ics` file: `RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=MO;UNTIL=20211224T225959Z;BYDAY=TH`

I'm parsing all entries to my custom Entry-Class for further processing. I do this with `for entry in cal.walk()` and check if the entry is a `VEVENT`. Is there a way without manually parsing this `RRULE` line and create new entries for every repeated calendar entry?

For example: I have something every week for the next 12 weeks and I want a unique entry for every week.

I read the documentation, but it's pretty limited and browsing the source code did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found [this](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/python-recurring-ical-events) package. There doesn't seem to be an easy way with just `icalendar`.